# What is the name of the book which Ashwatthama narrated to a south Indian saint?

Tags: mahabharata, book-recommendation, saint, ashwatthama

I am looking for the name of the book which Ashwatthama narrated to a South Indian saint.

Stories go like this,

> A saint wanted to write an authentic Mahabharat and later received a boon from [*I don't know*]. The boon given by the [*God, maybe*] was like this, you go to a particular temple during aarti and the first person to leave the aarti is the Ashwatthama and ask him that I told him to help you write Mahabharata.

I can't recall the name of the saint or the name of the book. Please let me know if that version of Mahabharat is available in English language as well.